# Creating Masonry items with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I need to be able to create Masonry `item`s in jQuery rather than HTML. However, the below fails to output anything. By contrast, the commented out HTML equivalent works perfectly.

Is there a workaround for this?

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="feed">
    <!-- this would work fine:
        <div class="item">hey</div>
        <div class="item">hi</div>
        <div class="item">hello</div>
    -->
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("div.feed").html("<div class='item'>hey</div><div class='item'>hi</div><div class='item'>hello</div>");
```

**EDIT**

To be clear, that jQuery is appending what it's supposed to where the commented out HTML is. My issue is making Masonry respond to that - the three divs should be side-by-side.

Comment: It works for me, is the question about Masonry laying out stuff?

Comment: Take a look at my edit - does that clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masonry lays out once and only once unless you bind `resize` to it using either one of

```
msnry.bindResize()
// or with jQuery
$container.masonry('bindResize')
```

In which case, when the window is resized, the Masonry instance will reload itself by recollecting the items and laying them out again.  So there are two options to your problem.

- Call `window.resize()` after adding items if you've binded resize.
- Use masonry's `appended` method instead (passing the elements as a fragment): http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended

**Edit**:
You should really use the `appended` method.  Here's an example using your html elements.

```
var $fragment = $("<div class='item'>hey</div> \
    <div class='item'>hi</div><div class='item'>hello</div>");
$('div.feed').append($fragment).masonry('appended', $fragment);
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/5xfpF/

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I tried `$container.masonry( 'appended', '<div class="item">Welcome</div><div class="item">hi</div><div class="item">hello</div>');` but it didn't work - am I going about it in the wrong way?

Comment: It expects a jQuery element, not html.

Comment: I see. In that case, how would I pass the HTML above?

Comment: Thanks again. I'm afraid that's not outputting anything and the console is empty.

Comment: Here's the general idea for what you were asking before: http://jsfiddle.net/zazvs/4/